# how to use HashMap in Entity - Springboot

Tags: java

have Entity:

```
@Data
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
@Entity
public class League {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "league")
    private long id;

    private int leagueRound;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Club> leagueTeams;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "league_fixtures_maping",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "league_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "round_number")
    @Column(name = "games")
    private HashMap<Integer, List<Game>> leagueFixtures;

    // standard getters and setters
```

Integer is number of Round in leagueFixtures.
List it's list of Games(two Teams, scores etc) of oneRound.

but anytime I try to start App, I got error: *Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: java.util.HashMap collection type not supported for property: pl.com.k1313.g4g.domain.league.League.leagueFixtures*

how to properly use Map in my case?

Comment: Why wouldn't you make that `HashMap` a `Map`? You should be using `Map` whenever you can instead of the concrete `HashMap` class.

Comment: I did. Have the same error....:(

Comment: @ZackMacomber can you post your table structure too.